# How to build up a ML model for text classification which contains none 'natural language'?

Tags: machine-learning

I am looking for a model for text classification for our log notes analytics.

The challenge is that each note may contain none 'natural language' texts. For example, some notes are thread backtrace output with symbols, some notes are logging information from source code. And among these notes, some notes with description of how customer is using our product are the ones we want to classify.

Is there any ML model or approach that I could use for this text classification?

Below are some examples for different notes (I changed some content so no company confidential materials are shown):

backtrace info developer pasted for bug analysis:

```
func118 4563453 344 = SYSTEM_FUNC_1 0x00000efa34343 0x0000000009f333a0 0xffe3ebdfd700 <<<<<
Total of 1 API working thread(s)
(gdb) thread find 0x123456
Thread 670 has target id 'Thread 0x123456 (LWP 443)'
(gdb) t 670
[Switching to thread 670 (Thread 0x123456 (LWP 443))]
#0 0x35353453563abcd in __lock_func1_ ()
from /disks/folder1/xxx/xxx_folder1/info_folder/info2_dir/lib64/libpthread.so.0
(gdb) ebt
#0 __lock_func1_()
#1 _LOCK_F_10()
#2 func_mod_4()
#3 func_mod_5()
#4 ModCon::disconnect()
#5 ModCon::abort()
#6 ModServ::disconnect()
#7 ModServManager::disconnect()
#8 mod1::func1()
#9 mod1::func2()
```

Product log for issue analysis:

```
cpu/MOD/MOD2/log/
start_mod.log:
Thu Dec 24 00:01:12 UTC 2019 FUN: HG: FILE_A: stopping
Thu Dec 24 00:01:12 UTC 2019 FUN: FILE_A: stopping, timeout -22-
Thu Dec 24 00:01:12 UTC 2019 system-state: cleared FILE_A_start_complete
Thu Dec 24 00:01:12 UTC 2019 FUN: FILE_A: run thread still running: con_b.pl FUN_run 0
Thu Dec 24 00:01:12 UTC 2019 FUN: FILE_A: calling con_b.pl FUN_cleanup 0, time left: -160-
Thu Dec 24 00:01:12 2019 cli: con_a.pl: FUN_cleanup for FILE_A
Thu Dec 24 00:01:12 2019 cmd: con_a.pl: sp got xxx error, will try to act_xxx
Thu Dec 24 00:01:13 UTC 2019 FUN: FILE_A: action 1
Thu Dec 24 00:01:13 UTC 2019 FUN: FILE_A: action 1 complete
Thu Dec 24 00:01:13 UTC 2019 FUN: FILE_A: action 2
```

Customer related infomation for configuration (which will be most interested notes that I want to classify and retreive from all notes):

```
Customer xxx has created func_xxx to protect their data, 
they also perform daily backup of their data by using func_xxx2. 
They totally created xxx3 objects in each node...
```

Comment: Please give an example, some type of [MCVE]. What is a text input? What are some examples of classifications for them?

Comment: I have updated question give some example notes, please take a look